# Java Self Contained Packaging skipping most types

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to figure out how to use javapackager to create a self-contained Java application

Here's the output I'm seeing:

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Game -srcdir src -srcfiles Game.jar -appclass Main -name "Game" -title "Game demo"
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Bundler Windows Application Image skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
Bundler MSI Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
Advice to fix: Make sure to use fx:jar task to create main application jar.
```

I don't understand why it is suggesting that I use a fx:jar task for creating my jar. How do I need to create the jar using plain command line in order to get this working? I'm following example 7-2 from the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html

I'm able to compile, build the jar, and run the jar just fine.

Comment: Are you providing the fully-qualified class name (that is - including the package)? `Main` can't be a fully-qualified class name, as you must have at least one package in the hierarchy.

Comment: @sillyfly yes, it isn't a problem like that, the packager does produce output, just not for exe, msi etc.

Comment: I'm also using javapackager to create the jar, so you'd think it would work for -deploy?

javapackager -createjar -appclass Main -srcdir bin -outfile Game -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get this working. It can be a little finicky. I made a bare minimum demo project to create a self-contained distribution of a LWJGL application, which you can reference here: https://gitlab.com/charles-mulic/lwjgl-self-contained-app

Successfully tested both the resulting .exe and .exe installer. Should work for other platforms too, just need to adapt the batch script contents.

Here's a Gradle version that is a little cleaner: https://gitlab.com/charles-mulic/lwjgl-self-contained-app-gradle

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, but since I am in OSX, the bar script is not very helpful. What are the actual changes you performed so that the error message did disappear?